# Google Chrome new tab suddenly displays white bar under search box

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I don't know how this happened and I can't really think of a reason for it. Today after having opened Chrome for a dozen times it suddenly opened with a white bar beneath the search bar and the eight most opened sites.

I had a similar problem a while ago but resolved it by changing the zoom of the page because I unintentionally changed it before. However, this doens't seem to work now. I also tried resetting and changing the theme but it didn't help either. A common solution suggests that toolbars etc. could be responsible for such a problem but I have no toolbars installed and the three Plug-Ins I'm using haven't caused any problem in the past. Maybe it's related, maybe not but yesterday I upgraded to version `65.0.3325.146` (or Chrome did it automatically).

I don't really know what to do, the peculiar thing is that it suddenly was there. Hope someone knows what to do.

EDIT: Everything works as it always did in Incognito Mode.

Answer (score 0):

This annoying phenomenon may be a bug, see discussions [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=819781).

After investigating this problem using devtools in Chrome, I found that this problem is caused by CSS style of the container which holds the page. 
More details on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1301845/chrome-new-tab-page-background-image-not-filling-the-screen-by-height).

Then I come up with an idea, we can use tampermonkey to automatically insert this css rule to newtab. Spending some time learning how to do it, and here is my rather simple tampermonkey script:

```
// @match        https://*/_/chrome/newtab* 
// @grant        GM_addStyle 

GM_addStyle("body.des-mat { height: 100%; }");
```

But I think this solution is too 'dirty', hoping Chrome team can address this bug ASAP.

EDIT: With a minor update Google pushed to Chrome(from 65.0.3325.146 to 65.0.3325.162), this script is not working.

EDIT2: In the latest chromium(v67.0.3371.0), this bug seems to be addressed(by adding 'height:100%' to BODY tag, same as we did). So just wait for the new version of Chrome or switching to Chromium.