# Chrome new tab page background image not filling the screen by height

Tags: google-chrome

(probably a duplicate of [Google Chrome new tab suddenly displays white bar under search box](https://superuser.com/questions/1301385/google-chrome-new-tab-suddenly-displays-white-bar-under-search-box) but I can't bump others' questions)

It got broken a day ago, now it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30XLG.png
The bottom part is missing, same with other themes that worked before.

I tried disabling extensions, to no avail. It works properly in incognito mode though.

Looking into the page's code I noticed that while in incognito mode the background image is applied to the HTML element, in the standard mode it's applied to the BODY tag which does not have the "height: 100%" rule. When I apply it manually it fixes the problem, but I don't know how to do that automatically. Stylish and similar addons don't apply styles to new tabs and the trick with custom.css doesn't work anymore (updates making everything worse as usual).

Any ideas how to fix it? Roll back to a previous version maybe?

Comment: Well... roll back to a previous version & tell us if that worked...

Answer (score 0):

I write a short tampermonkey script to automatically insert css rule to newtab, and it works as expected:

```
// @match        https://*/_/chrome/newtab*
// @grant        GM_addStyle
GM_addStyle("body.des-mat { height: 100%; }");
```

Hope it can help you!

EDIT: Chrome on my PC bumped up from v65.0.3325.146 to v65.0.3325.162. Google seems to change the source code of the newtab in this minor new version and this script is not working at this moment.

EDIT2: Latest Chromium(v67.0.3371.0) doesn't have this bug, so just Wait for new version of Chrome or switching to Chromium.

Comment: Looks interesting, but it doesn't launch on the new tab for me. It also refused to save a userscript of just these 3 lines untill I added more metadata like @name and stuff.

Comment: Yes, other metadatas are needed, I just write codes critical to this solution.